# horizontal Bootstrap Thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have problem in Bootstrap Thumbnails.
my thumbnails is like that:
[img01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQvMl.png). but want to be horizontal.
What am i doing ?

My Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="hrs" align="center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/AxMahsool.jpg" alt="AxMahsool01" class="img-responsive" />
          <img src="img/AxMahsool.jpg" alt="AxMahsool02" class=" img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/AxMahsool.jpg" alt="AxMahsool03" class=" img-responsive" />
          <img src="img/AxMahsool.jpg" alt="AxMahsool04" class=" img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Css:

```
.hrs{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have them in separate `<div class="row">` containers. What you should do is put all of your images in the same row container(so take out the second `<div class="row">`) -and/or- try adding this code to your CSS:

```
.thumbnail>img { display: inline-block; }
```